# How to paste to terminal linux in virtual box with mac keyboard?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I'm using Mac and I've installed debian linux on virtual box.
I want to copy a URL from my Mac to terminal linux in virtual box. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it a terminal emulator window, or an actual terminal? (If it's the former, turn Clipboard Sharing on, and press Command+Shift+C.)

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions? Also, are you talking about a TTY window or a terminal emulator?

Comment: I couldn't install guest additions because my debian doesn't have X.Org. I'm using TTY directly.

Comment: There's a [similar question on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/195436/ubuntu-server-vm-copy-paste), but unfortunately no better answer than "use SSH" yet.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sometimes, it's just easier to open a terminal on the Mac and then SSH to the VirtualBox guest.  That avoids a lot of the hassle of changing focus, etc.

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same problem.   After making sure Clipboard Sharing is on, Ctrl+Shift+V to paste into the terminal in debian.

Comment: I have the same problem. This does not work.

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote up a guide to getting copy-and-paste working between OS X and Ubuntu on VirtualBox as it had been frustrating me. Maybe of help to someone who comes across this question:

http://blog.nostopbutton.com/2013/08/24/setup-copy-and-paste-between-os-x-and-linux-virtualbox/

Comment: Your tutorial discusses copy & paste under X, whereas the OP is asking about the Linux console with no GUI.

Comment: found it! it was under tweaks app

Comment: Downvoted. This is why you are supposed post *answers* on stack exchange, not *links to answers*. `Something unexpected happened while accessing this website. It looks like it doesn't have an active domain connection upgrade to link the requested domain name to the WordPress.com site.`

Answer (score 2):

**First**
Install Guest Additions CD (`Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD image`).

**Activate clipboard sharing**
Then after a reboot, in Virtualbox go to `Machine->Settings->General->Advanced` and set
`Shared Clipboard: Bidrectional`

**Change VirtualBox Host Key**
In `Vitualbox/Preferences/Input/Virtual Machine/Host Key Combination`
choose sth different then <kbd>⌘</kbd>

**Key Mapping**:
For the `cmd/ctrl` mapping for me adding the English (Macintosh) keyboard seems to be the most comfortable solution :)

Go to `Ubuntu Settings->Text Entry`
(I guess in older versions it might be in Keyboard Layout Settings)
Under `Input sources to use:` hit plus (+)
add `English (Macintosh)`

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64bit in VirtualBox 5.0.4

Comment: The question is about using a TTY, not a full blown desktop installation with a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I've put together [a page describing how to do this](http://erluko.github.io/howto/pasting-service-for-virtualbox)

The short version is that you can do this using AppleScript and a custom keyboard shortcut.

AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set input to input as text
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with currentChar in the characters of input
            set cID to id of currentChar
            set used to false
            repeat with r in {{48, 29}, {49, 18}, {50, 19}, {51, 20}, {52, 21}, {53, 23}, {54, 22}, {55, 26}, {56, 28}, {57, 25}, {45, 27}, {46, 47}, {47, 44}, {61, 24}}
                if first item of r is equal to cID then -- 0-9 -./=
                    key code (second item of r)
                    set used to true
                end if
            end repeat
            repeat with r in {{42, 28}, {43, 24}} -- *+
                if first item of r is equal to cID then
                    key code (second item of r) using shift down
                    set used to true
                end if
            end repeat
            if not used then
                keystroke currentChar
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

This script is also useful for defeating password fields which foolishly prevent pasting.

Comment: Like apparently every single "solution" to this issue on Stack Exchange, this does not work at all. `The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed to send keystrokes.”` I "retraced my steps and tried again" as you said, and same result. This is not a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I use ubuntu from my windows machine with virtualbox connected with PuTTY, FileZilla etc.

(Not using default virtualbox console)

Here is how you can setup yours from scratch:

```
### Setup Virtualbox:
    https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
    install ubuntu from their website
### Launch Ubuntu from Virtualbox Console:
    sudo apt-get install openssh-server
    sudo systemctl start ssh
    sudo systemctl status ssh
    netstat -tulpn
        # see ubuntu port 22 open and ssh running
    sudo poweroff
### Virtualbox: 
    settings - network - Advanced - Adapter Type: PCNet Fast 3 - Port Forwarding
    Name: SSH, Protocol: TCP, Host Port (Windows): 3022, Guest Port (Ubuntu): 22
    right click - start - headless start
### PuTTY: 
    Seesion: Localhost Ubuntu: <your_user> -p
        Host: <your_user>@127.0.0.1
        Port: 3022
    Window - Colums: 130, Rows: 24
    Scrollback lines: 10000
    Appearance - Cursor: Vertical + Blinks
    Font Courier New  - Regular - 12px
    Behaviour - Window Title: Localhost Ubuntu
    Full screen on ALT + ENTER
    Connection Data - Auto login Username: <your_user>
    Session - SAVE!

### FTP:
    Host: localhost 
    Port: 3022
    SFTP (SSH FTP)
    Logon Type: normal
        <your_user>
        <pass>
    Transfer settings: limit max. conenction: 4

### Git BASH:
    ssh -p 3022 <your_user>@localhost

### Enable SSH Root Login: (Use only on localhost, security advice!)
    # Set a password for root account first and then enable root account:
        sudo passwd root
        sudo passwd -u root
        # Reverting Back: (lock the root account)
            sudo passwd -l root
    # Enable SSH root login:
        sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
            # PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
            PermitRootLogin yes
        sudo systemctl restart ssh

### Virtualbox Windows Headless Start
    # Make a .lnk shortcut with target or .bat batch file
    "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm "UbuntuMin" --type headless
    "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" controlvm "UbuntuMin" poweroff
    Add shortcuts to start menu -> ubuntu START & STOP - change .ico - right click - pin to start
```